# Unity3D: adjust camera to don't cover iOS status bar

Tags: ios, user-interface, unity-game-engine, statusbar

my Unity3d app gets rejected because it covers permanently the iOS status bar. That was actually my design decision but now I have to change it. My question is: what is the right way to resolve this problem, because if i just enable iOS status bar, the bar will be drawn on top of my app UI at the top border?

Is there a global setting? 
Do I have to adjust the camera viewport? How?
Only adjust the GUI position at the top border? How to do that to fit every iOS device resolution?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that is why they rejected the app? because I know a lot of games (made with Unity) that have the status bar covered like *Crossy Road*, *Piano Tiles*, *Dancing Line*, etc., you slide twice from the top to show the notification center (with the status bar).

Comment: Yes, i was very surprised too. I think the point is that the app is not a game. Its more an interactive, animated magazine with 3D models of some products, AR fun and so on. Its very disappointing that I have to break the immersion to follow apple guide lines but that is exactly what they wrote in the rejection mail.